# Is there a name for the style clash of moving objects from the background in cartoons?

Tags: animation, terminology, technique

You know how you could always tell which elements in a scene of Road Runner was part of the Coyote's trap?

[image: Wile setting up a spring punch on a rock that suspiciously looks like it is going to move]

Or how characters have a much simpler art style from the rest of the background?

[image: Scooby Doo and the crew entering a spooky dark swamp shack]

I understand it is a product of not having the budget to dedicate as much detail to the moving parts, which have to be redrawn every frame, but is there a specific name for that practice, or its resulting clash of visual style?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's as a result of the practicalities involved in painting millions of frames in traditional "cell animation". It's not so much a budget restraint, more of a time constraint. It would take too long to paint more detail. As far as I know,  I don't think there's is name for the style difference. Not everything has a name. See this related question: [Difference in style between foreground and background objects in 2D animation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137026/difference-in-style-between-foreground-and-background-objects-in-2d-animation/137030#137030)

Comment: Not millions @Kerr a hand drawn feature movie only has only about 86400 frames 60*60*12*2 so only about 1/10 million

Comment: @joojaa - I was using hyperbole ;)